# Generating an nonce for Content Security Policy and all scripts - How to make it match/persist for each page load?

Tags: php, functions, filters, hooks, security

Hooking into the `script_loader_tag` hook and generating random strings is no problem, but how can I generate them once per page load and use them in both `wp_head` and `script_loader_tag`?

I'd really like to upgrade my **CSP**, but all the plugins I've found to do it mangle minification.

Comment: edit your question to show the code you tried.

Comment: I can't come up with any reasonably clean code that could possibly work, so I've tried no code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you would not use the `wp_head` action. That happens in the head part of the HTML output. To send a Content-Security-Policy header, or modify an existing one, you would want to hook into the `wp_headers` filter instead.

As for generating the nonce, you don't want to use a WordPress based nonce, as those are not unique per page load. You will want each load to have a random number generated.

As for using the same number in the `wp_headers` and the `script_loader_tag`, well, you just, you know, use the same number in both places. Generate the number in the body of your plugin code, put it in a global variable, then reference that variable from both functions hooked to those filters.

Comment: Are you able to suggest what we can use to generate nonces in Wordpress for use in a CSP please?

Comment: @zigojacko Well, php's random_int or random_bytes would be the obvious place to start from.

Answer (score 0):

WP's nonces aren't true nonces as they are valid for about 24 hours. So, if you use the same string in `wp_create_nonce( $action )` then WP will always generate the same nonce for a 24 hour period.